# clear select options onclick

Tags: jquery, select

I have written the following code to limit the options in a select menu based on the option selected in a previous select menu.  It works fine the first time you select the #distrito, however if I make a mistake or change my mind in what district is selected it keeps the options that were the result of my first choice AND my second choice.  So what I am looking for is a way to reset the selector to its default state at the beginning and then proceed through the rest of the function, so that only the appropriate class of options is available.  In the HTML each class below is set to style="display:none" as default.

```
 function facilityDistrict() {
 var x = $('#distrito').val();
 if (x == 'altoMolocue') {
   $(".altoMolocue").show();
    }
 else if (x == 'Chinde') {
 $('.Chinde').show();
 }
 else if (x == 'Gile') {
$('.Gile').show();
}
else if (x == 'Ile') {
$('.Ile').show();
}
else if (x == 'Inhassunge') {
$('.Inhassunge').show();
}
else if (x == 'MdC') {
$('.MdC').show();
}
else if (x == 'Mopeia') {
$('.Mopeia').show();
}
else if (x == 'Morrumbala') {
$('.Morrumbala').show();
}
else if (x == 'Namacurra') {
$('.Namacurra').show();
}
else {
$('.Pebane').show();
 }
}
```

Comment: You should store the default options on the page load in a Javascript object so you can restore it again if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably add another class to each of the options which can be easily referenced to hide all of them at the beginning of the function:

```
function facilityDistrict() {
  var x = $('#distrito').val();
  if (
    x == 'altoMolocue' ||
    x == 'Chinde' ||
    x == 'Gile' ||
    x == 'Ile'
   ) {
     // Give all relevant elements the 'option' class
     $('.option').hide();
     $("."+x).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Based on your answer here I ended up doing something similar, pretty much same idea but in reverse.  Not sure if it is proper code but it seems to work.  After stating my variable, I took each class and set it to hide, ex. $(".altoMolocue").hide();  Then I ran my if statements.  So onclick it always hides everything and then repopulates based on the newly selected district